# Error: Not found wrapperScript: /home/vsts/work/1/s/gradlew

Tags: android, azure, gradle, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm trying to add my Android project to Azure DevOps, but I'm encountering an error during the build process. The error message I'm seeing is:

```yaml
Starting: Build APK
==============================================================================
Task         : Gradle
Description  : Build using a Gradle wrapper script
Version      : 2.219.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle
==============================================================================
##[error]Error: Not found wrapperScript: /home/vsts/work/1/s/gradlew
Finishing: Build APK
```

here's my Azure Pipelines YAML file:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - task: Gradle@2
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: 'MyApp'
      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
      gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
      tasks: 'assembleDebug'
    displayName: 'Build APK'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      contents: '**/*.apk'
      targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    displayName: 'Copy APK files to artifact staging directory'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
    displayName: 'Publish artifacts'
```

I have ensured that the Gradle wrapper files (gradlew and gradlew.bat) are included in my Git repository by removing them from the .gitignore file and pushing the changes. However, the error still persists. Am I missing any other files?

This is the current structure of my Git repository:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWICM.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the gradle wrapper file is not found when you run the pipeline.

According to this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops) the working directory should be set to:-

```
$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/AndroidApps/MyApp/gradlew
```

and the gradle wrapper file should be set to the file path in the root of your repository where your gradle wrapper file exist like below:-

```
$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/AndroidApps/MyApp/gradlew
```

Also, verify if MyApp is present in your repository for the working directory command to work.

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-latest'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    tasks: 'assembleDebug test'
  displayName: gradlew assembleDebug test

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '**/*.apk'
    targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
  displayName: Copy .apk files to artifact staging directory

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    artifactType: 'container'
  displayName: Publish artifacts
```

If the issue persists raise an issue in this [**link**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps?q=android%20pipeline)