# Android project building with Gradle fails in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: android, azure, gradle, azure-devops

I'm trying to build an Android application with the Gradle task in an Azure DevOps pipeline

[image]

but it fails with the message "Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0."
[image: Azure DevOps Gradle task failure]

This is the log:

```
2023-08-31T19:55:34.0254000Z * What went wrong:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.0354540Z A problem occurred configuring root project 'Prepara2'.
2023-08-31T19:55:34.0455410Z > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
2023-08-31T19:55:34.0555180Z    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0.
2023-08-31T19:55:34.0656610Z      Required by:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.0758410Z          project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.0
2023-08-31T19:55:34.0859370Z       > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.0959660Z           - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1060840Z               - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1161890Z               - Other compatible attribute:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1285110Z                   - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1387100Z           - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1387850Z               - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1489260Z               - Other compatible attributes:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1590880Z                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1692450Z                   - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1780470Z                   - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1860490Z           - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.1962210Z               - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
2023-08-31T19:55:34.2060230Z               - Other compatible attribute:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.2097130Z                   - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
2023-08-31T19:55:34.2198720Z           - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.2299060Z               - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
2023-08-31T19:55:34.2400480Z               - Other compatible attributes:
2023-08-31T19:55:34.2502100Z                   - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
2023-08-31T19:55:34.2603660Z                   - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
2023-08-31T19:55:34.2705300Z                   - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
```

- I have changed the java version in the app build.gradle file compileOptions from JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 to JavaVersion.VERSION_11
- I have changed the plugins com.android.aplication version in the build.gradle file using 8.1.0 and 8.0.0
- I have tested the Gradle@2 and Gradle@3 tasks in the Azure DevOps pipeline

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Java version used by your project and **`gradle plugin`** is same. That is Java 11.

In your **`build.gradle file`** set the compile option like below:-

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}
```

*And update the gradle version to the latest one like below:-*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
    }
}
```

And make sure the dependencies are correctly imported in the **build.gradle** file like below:-

[image]

My Gradle Android YAML script with `gradle clean cache task`

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
  displayName: 'Gradle Build'
- script: 'gradlew clean' # Clean gradle cache
  displayName: 'Clean Gradle Cache'
```

Refer my [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76636182/error-not-found-wrapperscript-home-vsts-work-1-s-gradlew/76687043#76687043) to run gradle task

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple and pure. I just set JDK for the pipeline.

The only thing you need to do is set the correct JDK version for the Gradle@3.

**(1) How to do it when I know my JDK version in Androud Studio IDE?**

In my case,
I create the android pipeline by default from Azure DevOps,
And then I found out that I only need to add these description in the Gradle@3

```yaml
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
```

for example, my full case is

```yaml
- task: Gradle@3
  displayName: Build Android Apk
  inputs:
   
    gradleWrapperFile: './gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: "assembleDebug"
```

My vmImage is macos-latest too.

I use the latest version of Android Studio IDE. And it use
JDK 17. So I just need to set it into correct version

```
jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
```

**(2) Where to get my android studio IDE's JDK version ?**

The JDK of Android Studio IDE is often different to your mac os.
What is the JDK version of my Android IDE?
If you are mac os x user, you can use this command to get correct version.

```bash
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
```

In my example, it shows

```
openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231, mixed mode)
```

The easiest way is to refer to this document.
https://developer.android.com/build/jdks
It currently shows JDK 17 for the latest Android Studio IDE.

- Upgrade you Android Studio IDE,
- build your android project,
- commit and push the code on the git,
- Setup Azure android pipeline in the JDK 17 in your Gradle@3
- build your apk on Azure DevOps.

Great :D